# Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type int--

Tags: sql-server, datetime

```
DECLARE @minusDate   DATETIME 
DECLARE @unixTimeConst  INTEGER 
DECLARE @unixBeginDate  DATETIME

SELECT 
    @counterWS =  COUNT(*) 
FROM  
    wmservice_min_max 
WHERE    
    @unixBeginDate + LASTTIME / @unixTimeConst  < @minusDate
```

`LASTTIME` is a column with datetime type.

I am getting the following error :

> Disallowed implicit conversion from data type datetime to data type int, table 'wmservice_min_max', column 'LASTTIME'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

Comment: `LASTTIME / @unixTimeConst` why are you dividing a date by an integer?

Comment: Use DateAdd and other functions designated for Date manipulation.  Or use DateDiff to convert the dates to number of seconds from a specific date. Then you can perform mathmatical operations on them.

Answer (score 1):

U can modify the query like this, but i doubt logically what you are expecting  you would get as output.

```
            DECLARE @minusDate   DATETIME 
            DECLARE @unixTimeConst  INTEGER 
            DECLARE @unixBeginDate  DATETIME
            DECLARE @counterWS INT

            SELECT 
                @counterWS =  COUNT(*) 
            FROM  
               #TEMP
            WHERE    
                CAST((@unixBeginDate + LASTTIME) AS INT) / @unixTimeConst  < @minusDate
```

Comment: WC :). could you pls mark it as the correct answer ?